# Same images are appearing multiple times in grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I had developed an album app in which I am using grid View. The app is working but every time when I press back button and return to my app, one more copy of image is appearing in  the grid view. For instance, I have 7 images in the grid view, when I press back button and then return to app, it becomes 14. Next time total images will be 21 and so on. I am reading images from SD card. My app is having full screen functionality, so same thing occurs that case as well. I am not getting why it happened. Below, I am posting my code:

**Album Activity**

```
public class Album3Activity extends Activity {
static File [] mediaFiles;
static File imageDir;
static GridView gridView;
ImageAdapter adapter;
Intent in;
static String name = null;
static ArrayList<Bitmap> bmpArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
static ArrayList<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>();
public static final String TAG = "Album3Activity";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);
    imageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+
             "/diplomat");
    mediaFiles = imageDir.listFiles();
    //Log.d("Lenght of images",""+mediaFiles.length);
    for(File file : mediaFiles)
    {
        bmpArray.add(convertToBitmap(file));
        fileName.add(readFileName(file));
        Log.d(TAG + "bmpArray Size", ""+bmpArray.size());
        Log.d(TAG, "call to convertToBitmap");
    }//for

    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, bmpArray, fileName);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int      position,
                long arg3) {
            in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreen.class);
            in.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}//onCreate

public static Bitmap convertToBitmap(File file) 
{
    URL url = null;
    try 
    {
        url = file.toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, e1.toString());
    }//catch

    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try
    {
       bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
       //bmp.recycle();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: "+e.toString());
    }//catch
    return bmp;
}//convertToBitmap

public String readFileName(File file){
    String name = file.getName();
    return name;
}//readFileName
}//class
```

**Image Adapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Activity act;
ArrayList<Bitmap> mFiles;
static ArrayList<String> mName;
public static final String TAG = "ImageAdapter";
static String name = null;
public ImageAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<Bitmap> mFiles, ArrayList<String>     mName) {
    super();
    this.act = act;
    this.mFiles = mFiles;
    ImageAdapter.mName = mName;
    Log.d("mfiles", "" + this.mFiles.size());
}// ImageAdapter

public int getCount() {
    return mFiles.size();
}// getCount

public Object getItem(int postion) {
    return mFiles.get(postion);
}// getItem

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}// getItemId

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tv;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater li = act.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        Log.d("tag", "null");
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);
        view.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        view.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        convertView.setTag(view);
    }// if
    else {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }// else
    view.iv.setImageBitmap(mFiles.get(position));
    view.tv.setText(readName(position));
    Log.d(TAG, "getView method called");
    return convertView;
}// getView

public static String  readName(int position) {
    String name = mName.get(position);
    return name;
}//readName

    }// ImageAdapter
```

**FullScreen.java**

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnGestureListener{
ImageView imageView1;
ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getParent(), Album3Activity.bmpArray, Album3Activity.fileName);
Button avbryt, camera, trash, opendialog, slett, 
    avbryt1, epost, mms, avbryt2, facebook;
TextView textView;
ImageButton btnNext, btnPrevious;
GestureDetector gesturedetector = null;
Intent in; 
int touches; 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);
    viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    in = getIntent();
    touches = in.getExtras().getInt("id");
    imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches)); 
    textView.setText(ImageAdapter.readName(touches));

    btnNext = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnPrevious = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);

    trash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trash);
    trash.setOnClickListener(this);

    opendialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opendialog);
    opendialog.setOnClickListener(this);

    avbryt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.avbryt);
    avbryt.setOnClickListener(this);

    camera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.camera_albumbutton);
    camera.setOnClickListener(this);

    gesturedetector=new GestureDetector(this, this);
}//onCreate

    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnNext:
        Animation animationNext = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.btn_style_next);
        btnNext.startAnimation(animationNext);
        nextView();
        break;

    case R.id.btnPrevious:
        Animation animationPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.btn_style_previous);
        btnPrevious.startAnimation(animationPrevious);
        previousView();
        break;

    case R.id.trash:
        final Dialog dialog  = new Dialog(FullScreen.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.trashdialog);
        slett = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.slett);
        avbryt1 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.avbryt);

        slett.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                            "/diplomat/"+ ImageAdapter.readName(touches));
                Log.d("FullScreen Path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.d("Hi1 touches value", ""+touches);
                try
                {

                    if(touches == (Album3Activity.bmpArray.size() - 1))
                    {
                        file.delete();
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED
                                , Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/diplomat")));
                        Album3Activity.bmpArray.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new bmpArray size", ""+Album3Activity.bmpArray.size());

                        Album3Activity.fileName.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new fileName size", ""+Album3Activity.fileName.size());

                        Album3Activity.gridView.invalidateViews();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        touches = Album3Activity.bmpArray.size() - touches;
                        Log.d("FullScreen delete:if block", "Updated touches value:"+touches);

                        do
                        {
                            Log.d("FullScreen:delete if", "in while loop");
                            imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
                            textView.setText(ImageAdapter.readName(touches));
                            break;
                        }//do
                        while(Album3Activity.bmpArray.isEmpty() == false);
                    }//if
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("fullscreen:delete else", "else block executed");
                        file.delete();
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED
                                , Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/diplomat")));

                        Album3Activity.bmpArray.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new bmpArray size", ""+Album3Activity.bmpArray.size());

                        Album3Activity.fileName.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new fileName size", ""+Album3Activity.fileName.size());

                        Album3Activity.gridView.invalidateViews();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
                        textView.setText(ImageAdapter.readName(touches));

                    }//else
                }//try
                catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                    Log.d("Fullscreen delete method", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(FullScreen.this, "No more image left to diaplay"
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }//catch
                finally
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }//finally
            }//onClick
        });

        avbryt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }//onClick
        });
        dialog.show();
        break;

    case R.id.opendialog:
        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(FullScreen.this);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.openbuttondialog);
        epost = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.epost);
        mms = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.mms);
        facebook = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.facebook);
        avbryt2 =(Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.openavbryt);

        epost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }//onClick
        });

        mms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }//onClick
        });

        facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }//onClick
        });

        avbryt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog1.cancel();
            }//onClick
        });
        dialog1.show();
        break;

    case R.id.avbryt:
        break;

    case R.id.camera_albumbutton:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }//switch

}//onClick

private void previousView() {
    if(touches > 0){
        touches = touches - 1;
        imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
        textView.setText(ImageAdapter.readName(touches));
        viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation1);
        viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation1);
        viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
    }//if
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No image left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }//else
    Log.d("Switcher", "previousView");
}//previousView

private void nextView() {
    if(touches < Album3Activity.bmpArray.size() - 1){
        touches = touches + 1;
        imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
        textView.setText(ImageAdapter.readName(touches));
        viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation);
        viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation);
        viewSwitcher.showNext();
    }//if
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No image left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }//else
    Log.d("Switcher", "nextView");
}//nextView

public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 50;
int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;


public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    float ev1X = e1.getX();
    float ev2X = e2.getX();
    Log.d("On", "Onfling");
    //Get distance of X (e1) to X (e2)
    final float xdistance = Math.abs(ev1X - ev2X);
    //Get veclocity of cusor
    //Váº­n tá»‘c = sá»‘ Ä‘iá»ƒm áº£nh (px) / giÃ¢y
    final float xvelocity = Math.abs(velocityX);

    //Váº­n tá»‘c chuyá»ƒn Ä‘á»•i X > 100 vÃ  khoáº£ng cÃ¡ch tá»« Ä‘iá»ƒm kÃ©o Ä‘áº§u Ä‘áº¿n Ä‘iá»ƒm kÃ©o cuá»‘i > 100
    if( (xvelocity > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) && (xdistance > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) )
    {
        if(ev1X > ev2X)//Switch Left
        {
            previousView();
        }
        else//Switch Right
        {
            nextView();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("on touch","touch");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    this.gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

    }//FullScreen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared all your variables as `static`? `static` variable maintains only one copy in the application. It adds the fileName to the same copy. If you don't want duplicate values better use `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

```
static HashSet<Bitmap> bmpArray = new HashSet<Bitmap>();
static HashSet<String> fileName = new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: What he said. Try removing the static keyword and see what happens!

Comment: @Damian I know removing `static` will solve the problem,but I assumed he wanted those `static` variables to be accessed in other `classes` also

Comment: Sure. Another way to fix would be to call bmpArray = new HashSet<Bitmap>(); in onCreate just before looping through the mediaFiles

Comment: @Nishant on removing static, it is working fine but image is not appearing now in fullscreen. On click of image, it gave me null pointer exception. I can't use hashset since they are not sorted, so I won't be able get an image at a particular index. Another approach would be like I retrieve all images from hashset and store them in arraylist and then use arraylist in my program which would be a bit lengthy procedure. May be, I am missing some thing, can you please suggest me what to do?

Comment: My problem has been solved now. Thanks for help Nishant. I am posting my updated code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now when you leave the app a bundle is being created, and when you return it is used by the system to restore you to where you were (giving you your original seven) and then you are adding them again because `onCreate` runs again.

You need to check for a savedInstanceState, and if it exists, don't do anything.  You should have this in all of your `onCreate` methods.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null) { 
         // Do your oncreate stuff because there is no bundle    
    } 
// Do stuff that needs to be done even if there is a saved instance, or do nothing 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**AlbumActivity**

```
public class Album3Activity extends Activity {
File [] mediaFiles;
File imageDir;
static GridView gridView;
ImageAdapter adapter;
Intent in;
String name = null;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmpArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
ArrayList<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>();
public static final String TAG = "Album3Activity";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);
    imageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+
             "/diplomat");
    mediaFiles = imageDir.listFiles();
    //Log.d("Length of images",""+mediaFiles.length);
    try
    {
        for(File file : mediaFiles)
        {
            bmpArray.add(convertToBitmap(file));
            fileName.add(readFileName(file));
            Log.d(TAG + "bmpArray Size", ""+bmpArray.size());
            Log.d(TAG, "call to convertToBitmap");
        }//for
    }//try
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(Album3Activity.this, "No files available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }//catch
    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, bmpArray, fileName);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreen.class);
            in.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}//onCreate

public static Bitmap convertToBitmap(File file) 
{
    URL url = null;
    try 
    {
        url = file.toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, e1.toString());
    }//catch

    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try
    {
       bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
       //bmp.recycle();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: "+e.toString());
    }//catch
    return bmp;
}//convertToBitmap

public String readFileName(File file){
    String name = file.getName();
    return name;
}//readFileName
}//class
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Activity act;
static ArrayList<Bitmap> mFiles;
static ArrayList<String> mName;
public static final String TAG = "ImageAdapter";
String name = null;
public ImageAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<Bitmap> mFiles, ArrayList<String> mName) {
    super();
    this.act = act;
    ImageAdapter.mFiles = mFiles;
    ImageAdapter.mName = mName;
    Log.d("mfiles", "" + ImageAdapter.mFiles.size());
}// ImageAdapter

public int getCount() {
    return mFiles.size();
}// getCount

public Object getItem(int postion) {
    return mFiles.get(postion);
}// getItem

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}// getItemId

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tv;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater li = act.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        Log.d("tag", "null");
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);
        view.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        view.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        convertView.setTag(view);
    }// if
    else {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }// else
    view.iv.setImageBitmap(mFiles.get(position));
    view.tv.setText(readName(position));
    Log.d(TAG, "getView method called");
    return convertView;
}// getView

public String readName(int position) {
    String name = mName.get(position);
    return name;
}//readName

}// ImageAdapter
```

**FullScreen**

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnGestureListener{
ImageView imageView1;
ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getParent(), ImageAdapter.mFiles, ImageAdapter.mName);
Button avbryt, camera, trash, opendialog, slett, 
    avbryt1, epost, mms, avbryt2, facebook;
TextView textView;
ImageButton btnNext, btnPrevious;
GestureDetector gesturedetector = null;
Intent in; 
int touches; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);
    viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    in = getIntent();
    touches = in.getExtras().getInt("id");
    imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches)); 
    textView.setText(adapter.readName(touches));
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED
            , Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/diplomat")));

    btnNext = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnPrevious = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);

    trash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trash);
    trash.setOnClickListener(this);

    opendialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opendialog);
    opendialog.setOnClickListener(this);

    avbryt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.avbryt);
    avbryt.setOnClickListener(this);

    camera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.camera_albumbutton);
    camera.setOnClickListener(this);

    gesturedetector=new GestureDetector(this, this);
}//onCreate
```

public void onClick(View v) {

```
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnNext:
        Animation animationNext = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.btn_style_next);
        btnNext.startAnimation(animationNext);
        nextView();
        break;

    case R.id.btnPrevious:
        Animation animationPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.btn_style_previous);
        btnPrevious.startAnimation(animationPrevious);
        previousView();
        break;

    case R.id.trash:
        final Dialog dialog  = new Dialog(FullScreen.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.trashdialog);
        slett = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.slett);
        avbryt1 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.avbryt);

        slett.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                            "/diplomat/"+ adapter.readName(touches));
                Log.d("FullScreen Path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.d("Hi1 touches value", ""+touches);
                try
                {

                    if(touches == (ImageAdapter.mFiles.size() - 1))
                    {
                        file.delete();
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED
                                , Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/diplomat")));
                        ImageAdapter.mFiles.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new bmpArray size", ""+ImageAdapter.mFiles.size());

                        ImageAdapter.mName.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new fileName size", ""+ImageAdapter.mName.size());

                        Album3Activity.gridView.invalidateViews();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        touches = ImageAdapter.mFiles.size() - touches;
                        Log.d("FullScreen delete:if block", "Updated touches value:"+touches);

                        do
                        {
                            Log.d("FullScreen:delete if", "in while loop");
                            imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
                            textView.setText(adapter.readName(touches));
                            break;
                        }//do
                        while(ImageAdapter.mFiles.isEmpty() == false);
                    }//if
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("fullscreen:delete else", "else block executed");
                        file.delete();
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED
                                , Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/diplomat")));

                        ImageAdapter.mFiles.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new bmpArray size", ""+ImageAdapter.mFiles.size());

                        ImageAdapter.mName.remove(touches);
                        Log.d("Hi2 new fileName size", ""+ImageAdapter.mName.size());

                        Album3Activity.gridView.invalidateViews();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
                        textView.setText(adapter.readName(touches));

                    }//else
                }//try
                catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                    Log.d("Fullscreen delete method", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(FullScreen.this, "No more image left to diaplay"
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }//catch
                finally
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }//finally
            }//onClick
        });

        avbryt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }//onClick
        });
        dialog.show();
        break;

    case R.id.opendialog:
        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(FullScreen.this);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.openbuttondialog);
        epost = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.epost);
        mms = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.mms);
        facebook = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.facebook);
        avbryt2 =(Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.openavbryt);

        epost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }//onClick
        });

        mms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }//onClick
        });

        facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }//onClick
        });

        avbryt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog1.cancel();
            }//onClick
        });
        dialog1.show();
        break;

    case R.id.avbryt:
        break;

    case R.id.camera_albumbutton:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }//switch

}//onClick

private void previousView() {
    if(touches > 0){
        touches = touches - 1;
        imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
        textView.setText(adapter.readName(touches));
        viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation1);
        viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation1);
        viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
    }//if
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No image left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }//else
    Log.d("Switcher", "previousView");
}//previousView

private void nextView() {
    if(touches < ImageAdapter.mFiles.size() - 1){
        touches = touches + 1;
        imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
        textView.setText(adapter.readName(touches));
        viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation);
        viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation);
        viewSwitcher.showNext();
    //}//if
    //else{
        //Toast.makeText(this, "No image left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        while(touches == (ImageAdapter.mFiles.size() - 1))
        {
            touches = 0;
            imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)adapter.getItem(touches));
            touches = touches + 1;
            break;
        }//while
    }//else
    Log.d("Switcher", "nextView");
}//nextView

public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 50;
int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;


public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    float ev1X = e1.getX();
    float ev2X = e2.getX();
    Log.d("On", "Onfling");
    //Get distance of X (e1) to X (e2)
    final float xdistance = Math.abs(ev1X - ev2X);
    //Get veclocity of cusor
    //Váº­n tá»‘c = sá»‘ Ä‘iá»ƒm áº£nh (px) / giÃ¢y
    final float xvelocity = Math.abs(velocityX);

    //Váº­n tá»‘c chuyá»ƒn Ä‘á»•i X > 100 vÃ  khoáº£ng cÃ¡ch tá»« Ä‘iá»ƒm kÃ©o Ä‘áº§u Ä‘áº¿n Ä‘iá»ƒm kÃ©o cuá»‘i > 100
    if( (xvelocity > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) && (xdistance > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) )
    {
        if(ev1X > ev2X)//Switch Left
        {
            previousView();
        }
        else//Switch Right
        {
            nextView();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("on touch","touch");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    this.gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

}//FullScreen
```